# What problem would be created by defining the argument of $z =0$ to be zero?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

What problem would be created by defining the argument of $z =0$ to be zero?

I know, If $x = y = 0$, the expression $tanθ = y/x$ has no meaning. What problems are created when we define $arg(0,0)=0$? Please explain.

Comment: No problem at all. But the question is, how is it useful?

Comment: Please Explain .

Comment: I come across this problem, when I was reading the book 'complex analysis  by Ponnusamy and Silverman (Birkhauser 2006) page no. 22 , question no:1.

Comment: Explanation: In math you can often define things any way you like. Only sometimes is this interesting or useful. For example Matrix multiplication may seem arbitrarily defined to a high school student. But it turns out to be very useful whereas other definitions that were wildly different would probably be not useful at all.

Comment: Then what is the point of asking this question?

Comment: A problem might be that one looses the identity $\arg(zw)=\arg(z)+\arg(w)\bmod{2\pi}$, valid for every nonzero $(z,w)$. // The point of the question is to make you think by yourself about the notions involved, a task you somehow escape by posting this here.